# Display sizes being recognised incorrectly

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport, vga

I'm running my MBP (Retina, 13-inch, early 2015) with two external monitors, one connected with a VGA-MiniDisplayPort and the other connected DVI-HDMI. They are arranged from left to right as in the picture below.

[image: Setup from L-R: HDMI-MiniDisplay; DVI-HDMI; InbuiltDisplay]

**The problem lies with the fact that my MacBook is recognising size of each monitor incorrectly. Below is a screenshot of the sizes the software thinks each screen is**

[image: Screenshot of monitors]

Is anybody able to explain why this is happening? I've tried unplugging and rebooting, rebooting whilst still plugged in, rebooting while only one is plugged in etc, etc...

**EDIT: I forgot to mention, that everything was working as normal until this morning, I'm not quite sure why it suddenly changed. Thanks for your answers so far**

**Solution: Swapped the cable out with a DVI-DisplayPort from a hotdesk. Not really a fix but it works for me...**

Comment: It doesn't care what size the displays are, only what resolution. As you haven't told us the resolutions, that's the best I can do right now.

Comment: Native resolutions are (left to right) : 1600 x 900; 1920 x 1080, 2560x1600.

Comment: It's not so much the native resolutions, as what they are currently set to - cos yup, for sure the picture doesn't match those numbers.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I'm not sure what they were set at. But I managed to "fix" my problem by nicking a DVI cable from one of the hotdesk computers...They don't get used very often anyway! Thanks for trying to help me anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The resolution is what determines the ‘size’ in the arrangement tab. In the photo, the middle monitor's resolution is so much less than the other displays. To adjust the resolution, go to the Display tab, then use the window on that specific display to choose a higher resolution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see your point, on changing the resolution it is slightly better, but still stretched out oddly. I forgot to mention in the main question, this problem only started this morning when I got to work, everything has been fine for the last two weeks on this setup.